# Awareness of exception in finally block, but without catch block

Tags: c#, exception, task, try-finally

Is it possible to determine if an exception was thrown without a catch block? Visual Studio is able to mine the exception out of my program state and put it as a pseudo-variable ($exception). Can I do something similar?

I'm working with external library, where I'm not able to modify try-finally block in there.

Here is a sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UnobservedTaskException"); // this is never printed out
        };
        // <external>
        // this is simplified code of referenced library, I can't change this
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                BeforeExecute();
                await Execute(); // the library uses reflection to get the proper method dynamically, this is just simplification
            }
            finally
            {
                AfterExecute();
            }
        });
        // exception is never rethrown, because the library isn't (a)waiting the task here :(
        // </external>
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    static void BeforeExecute()
    {
        // I use inheritance for this method, so I have to change it in just one place
        Console.WriteLine("BeforeExecute");
    }
    static void AfterExecute()
    {
        // I use inheritance for this method, so I have to change it in just one place
        Console.WriteLine("AfterExecute");
        // >>> can I have knowledge of the exception here? <<<
    }
    static Task Execute()
    {
        // I have multiple methods like this one, modifying this would be too much work
        Console.WriteLine("Execute");
        throw new Exception(); // the exception ends in abyss :(
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know specifics of the exception or just is there any exception or not?

Comment: The existence of exception would be sufficient. Specifics of the exception is not mandatory, but it would help.

Comment: Maybe you can get some information from registering to [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Evk for poining me in the right direction ;)